# assigning a item from a .json file to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, html

I have a `data1.json` file

[
    {
        "BID"      : "4569749",
    },
    {
         "BID"      : "466759",
    },
    {
        "BID"      : "4561149",
    },
]

I want to call this .json file inside another `abdv.js` file and assign the BIDs to a variable array

```
var R1;
```

i.e the value of `R1 = ['4569749', '466759', '4561149']`
How can i do this??

.html file(please note: I am specifying only those parts relevant to this quetsion and erased other parts)

Code follows:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="abdv.js"></script>
<script>

    loadABCD();

   </script>
```

abvd.js

Code follows:

```
function loadABCD()
    {


  var R1 = [];
$.get('data1.json', function (data) {
    var parsedArr = JSON.parse(data),
    i = 0, l = parsedArr.length;
    for (i; i < l; i++) {
        R1.push(parsedArr[i].BID);
    }
});




for(k=0;k<R1.length;k++)
 {
    document.write(R1);
}   
        // i will use R1 for later processing another function

    //  for(k=0; k<R1.length; k++)
    //  {
    //  obj = loadLevel4Obj(R1[k]);
    //  scene.add(obj);
    //    } 




    }
```

I also need help to read .json file into a javascript JSON object. I doubt whether the format of my json file is correct. Do i need to specify any other jquery related libs in the html file?? How do i check whether the BIDs are correctly stored in the variable R1.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've read your json file into a javascript JSON object (do you need help with that as well?)

```
var R1 = new Array();    

for(var i= 0 ; i< myJSON.length; i++){
   R1.push(myJSON[i].BID);
}
```

[EDIT]

Your document.write is happening before you've done any reading.

Remove it.

put a console.log instead in your anonymous callback from your $.get();

Make it look like this:

```
$.get('data1.json', function (data) {
    var parsedArr = JSON.parse(data),

    for (i = 0; i < parsedArr.length; i++) {
        R1.push(parsedArr[i].BID);
    }


    for(i=0; i< R1.length; i++)
      console.log("item " + i + " = " + R1[i]);
});
```

Also if your json file really looks like this:

```
[ { "BID" : "4569749", }, { "BID" : "466759", }, { "BID" : "4561149", }, ]
```

Then it needs to be fixed to remove the extraneous commas inside your objects. It should look like this:

```
[ { "BID" : "4569749" }, { "BID" : "466759" }, { "BID" : "4561149" } ]
```

I haven't tested this, but it looks like it should work to me.

Comment: `for..in` loop throw array? You will get in this loop all shared properties from `Array.prototype`.

Comment: I could not get it working: I will be more specific to my problem

Comment: You're doing a bunch of small things wrong... I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var R1 = [];
$.get('file.json', function (data) {
    var parsedArr = JSON.parse(data),
    i = 0, l = parsedArr.length;
    for (i; i < l; i++) {
        R1.push(parsedArr[i].BID);
    }
});
```

Comment: The OP makes no mention of jQuery... please edit your answer to remove said reference.

Answer (score -1):

Getting the json file with ajax, then process it and assign to R1:

```
function ajaxGetJson(url, callback){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            callback(eval(xmlhttp.responseText));
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

var R1;
ajaxGetJson('file.json', function(obj){
   R1 = obj.map(function(item){ return item.BID });
});
```

Some comments:

- I'm using `eval` instead of `JSON.parse` because your .json may not be in *strict* json format (as your example)
- As the question has tag `html5`, your browser for sure supports the `.map` method

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Comment: @Pinal Why? His Json file isn't in json strict format, so using `JSON.parse` would give you parse error. Eval can be used if it's used wisely as in this case.